# NGINX replace string in $args

Tags: nginx, regex

I would like to manipulate a parameter when the string /static/ exists on the src $arg_param in nginx.

```
    location ~ ^/customresize.php {
        if($args_param4 ~ /static/){
           #replace /static/ with /a/static/ 
        }
    }
```

As you understand there are parameters before an after so i just need to replace this part.
e.g

> https://my.site.io/customresize.php?z=2&w=200&h=100&sec=https://my.site.io/static/img.png

And on the url above replace /static/ with /a/static/.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    location ~ ^/customresize.php {
           if ( $args ~* ^z=([0-9]+)&w=([0-9]+)&h=([0-9]+)&src=https://([a-zAZ\.]+)/static/([a-zA-Z\./_-]+)$ ) {
           set $args zc=$1&w=$2&h=$3&src=https://$4/a/static/$5;
    }
```

This is actually working. It is not actual substitution but recreating the args. Tried to make the regex as inexpensive as well but can't make nginx accept [0-9]{n,m} for some reason only '+' works.

We simply save all previous options and replace the parts we want to replace.
The above can simplified to :

```
        location ~ ^/customresize.php {
           if ( $args ~* ^(.*)/static/(.*)$ ) {
           set $args $1/a/static/$2;
    }
```

For anyone having a hard time understanding the above one. I just tried to make the regex more performant.

Hope this helps anyone in need!